# Multiple Cell Vlookup Searches

Tags: excel, ms-office, vlookup

I trying to make this formula flexible so I can search the value in a cell in multiple file paths and different excel files to give me a result.

My data in each excel fiel is in the same table for each workbook.

```
=VLOOKUP(A6,IndirectEx("'C:\_Excel\ExcelExamples\VLOOKUP_External_Sample\[Workbookname.xlsx]Master'!MatlDB"),1,0)
```

Can you guys help.

Thanks-

Comment: [What's wrong with your formula?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So I have about 100 different file paths and different for names , I need the formula to change for every file path and excel file.

Comment: Do you have your file paths in a table or something? How do you plan to pass your file paths into the formula?

Comment: @urdearboy , the file paths are in a table .Example A1 through A50. The file names are in a table also. Example B1 through B50.

Comment: So you want the formula to look at "Workbook 1", if no result, look at "Workbook 2", if no result look at "Workbook 3", if no result ...?  Also, what's `INDIRECTEX()`?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes that right. I can post an example workbook later this afternoon. Indirectex is a formula that you can change the tab, you can remove the “ex” part of the formula.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think were on the same page , can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the file paths are stored in a table, and assuming that these are on a sheet named "Locations":

`=VLOOKUP(A6,INDIRECT(Locations!A1&Locations!B1),1,0)`

This should work, but the cell references are hardcoded. Not sure how you want to select the references.

Comment: I'm looking into it now. I'll follow up in a bit. Thanks

Comment: ,Yes that should work but, I'm trying to make it flexible to where I can change that cell reference on the fly.

Comment: Could you update your post with a mockup of what you want your input, that is how you would change your reference, and your output to look like?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. So after some trial and error my result, and if someone can find a better way or help me create a macro, that would be awesome.

```
="vlookup(A1,"&"'"&""&A2&"\"&"["&A3&"]"&"SampleTab'!$G$62:$DU$175,A4,0)"
```

So what I had to do is write it as I was creating a text. Copied it into a different cell and remove the quotations from the formula.

Then move the range P114 , C117 , C122 & Q113
A1 would be the lookup value cell.
A2 would be the file path cell.
A3 would be the workbook name (note it has to include the file extension)

The range (`SampleTab'!$G$62:$DU$175`) has to be hard coded for now. A4 would be the row where the data is at.